# Action Script 3 TextArea Component in IntellijIdea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea

I need TextField with scroll. I've found example: https://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html#htmlText

First error was `fl.controls` not found. 
I`ve added "d:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate 2020\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\" folder as source.

After that if I run example:

```
package {
import fl.controls.TextArea;

import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Test_AdobeAnimateComponents extends Sprite {
    public function Test_AdobeAnimateComponents() {
        var myText:String = "";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <b> tag to create <b>bold</b> text.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <i> tag to create <i>italic</i> text.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <u> tag to create <u>underlined</a> text.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <a> tag to create <a href='http://www.adobe.com'>links to other sites</a>.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <br> tag to create<br>new lines of text<br>whenever you want.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <font> tag to specificy different font <font color='#FF0000'>colors</font>, <font size='16'>sizes</font>, or <font face='Times New Roman'>faces</font>.</p>";
        myText += "<p>You can use the <img> tag to load images or SWF files:<br><img src='http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/images/logo.png'>.</p>";

        var myTextArea:TextArea = new TextArea();
        myTextArea.setSize(320, 100);
        myTextArea.move(10, 10);
        myTextArea.htmlText = myText;
        addChild(myTextArea);
    }
}
}
```

Error is now in `drawLayout()` of TextArea.as: background is null. It's because previous `drawBackground()` wants to find "upSkin". In `defaultStyles` upSkin is "TextArea_upSkin". Looks like I need some graphic file also.

"d:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Animate 2020\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\ComponentShim.fla" in same folder doesn't helped.

Comment: The **fl.controls** package is not a complete set of classes, they also need designs that are present if you add these components in Flash IDE (Professional or Animate). They will not work without these designs

Comment: Is there some template of design or at least rules to create it?

Comment: As I mentioned above — these are available in Adobe Flash IDEs. If you can't or won't use one, you probably need to resort to Flex SDK and MXML: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html

Comment: Tried this in Adobe Animate 2020 also with same Error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230528/action-script-3-textarea-component-in-adobe-animate

Comment: You need to actually add the **TextArea** component to the Library. Open components panel (I think it was Ctrl + F7 or Window -> Components, not sure, but you'll figure that one out) and drag **TextArea** to the Library so that Flash imports all the relevant materials into the Library. Don't remove anything of the imported things no matter however irrelevant they might seem. Then it is usable, via design or code.